# Form is timeouting on submitting without selected file in input type=file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, sails.js

Having a simple form as in the following js Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UdugW/ I am POSTing some form data to my node.js application (based on sails.js). This is one of the controller functions from `product` model:

```
  image_upload: function(req, res) {
    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
      console.log("request: " + util.inspect(req.body));

      if( req.files && req.files.product_image){
        fs.readFile(req.files.product_image.path, function (err, data) {

          var imageName = req.files.product_image.name;

          if(!imageName){
            console.log("There was an error with image upload : " + util.index(req.files.product_image));
            res.redirect("/product/new_product");
            res.end();
          } else {

            var newPath = UPLOAD_PATH + imageName;

            /// write file to uploads/fullsize folder
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
              res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
              res.end();
              return;
            }); 
          }   
        }); 
      }   
    }else if (req.body) {
        console.log("product_name: " + product_name);
        console.log("product_price: " + product_price);
        console.log("product_description: " + product_description);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end();
    }   
    else{
        console.log("request err");
        res.writeHead(500, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end();
    }   
  },
```

I have a problem when I do not select an image for upload, then my POST request is timing out.  Any ideas why this may happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9/10 with node.js app, when something is timing out, chances are you forgot to close the socket (at least in my experience). and in your case it's no different :-)

here is the problem: you have this if-statement

```
if( req.files && req.files.product_image){
```

but the poor guy doesn't have a matching else-statement :-(
so if that condition is not true... well, nothing happens. execution basically just ends and the browser is left waiting... for ever.

just adding an else-statment with a `res.end()` inside of it and you should be good.

So something like this

```
  if( req.files && req.files.product_image){
      //all the stuff you already have for when it matches
  }else{
    console.log("No files were included in the post");
    res.end();
  }
```

Comment: That was the issue. I had a problem with other `if`s as well. Thanks :)